# MemSQL table design for a word cloud

Tags: word-cloud, singlestore

I'm processing a twitter feed by storing the tweets into a table in memsql. The table has fields like tweet_id, posted_time, body, etc...

The table contains around 5 million tweets per day. total of a billion tweet for the whole period stored so far

The table is stored as a columnstore, with the tweet_id as a sharding key, and the posted_time as the columnstore clustering column.

It is working fine for all real-time analytics so far, and returns answers in sub-second if you query one day. The wider your date filters, the slower the query

The requirement is to generate a word cloud from the body field of the tweet. My question is; what is the best way to do it? I need the query to be efficient (takes seconds not minutes)
Keep in mind the following

- joins are not efficient for this big table.
- taking the body field for a few million tweets and break it down
  to words and then aggregate words and come up with the top ones is not efficient.

I believe a separate table will be needed, what could be the design for this table? suggestions please

Finally, my MemSQL cluster has 5 nodes, total of 1 TB of RAM, and 192 cores

Answer (score 0):

I don't think MemSQL is the best way to do this.  Your best bet is to index it with a search server/library like Apache Solr, or just use Apache Lucene as your backend.  That way, the queries needed for a word cloud, like "Give me all the counts of the top ranked n-words sorted by count" would return in seconds.